# Avoid Full Table Scan On Paged Nested Set

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-sets

I have a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) setup like so:

```
Node (Id, ParentId, LeftBounds, RightBounds, Level, Name)
```

`LeftBounds` has an index on it.

But when I attempt to select paged results,

```
SELECT * FROM Node ORDER BY LeftBounds ASC LIMIT 500000, 1000
```

Sql does a full table scan. Is there something else I should look at to avoid a full table scan?

This normally wouldn't be a huge problem, but with a table of several million rows, it takes ~3-5 seconds for the last page to load.

Comment: what DBMS are you running? is it [tag:mysql]?

Comment: `MySql` is what the test was on, yes.

Comment: you're having mysql scan _501000_ rows here. without a `where` clause performed using another indexed column, i'm not sure how meaningful this is. did you try `force index`? I don't expect a different result but worth a try, check this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LIMIT 5000000, 1000` clause requires MySQL to order your results in your result set, skip a half-million of them, and then display 1000.  It seems likely that MySQL has decided that's best done with a table scan. That's not surprising.

You might try a deferred join operation. The purpose of this is to reduce the size of the result set needing to be ordered.  It works like this.

```
SELECT Node.*
  FROM Node
  JOIN (
         SELECT id
           FROM Node
          ORDER BY LeftBounds ASC
          LIMIT 500000, 1000
       ) Subset ON Node.id = Subset.id
  ORDER BY Node.LeftBounds ASC
```

As you can see, this limits the big result set you need to wrangle to fewer columns, specifically `id` and `LeftBounds`.  It then uses the set of 1000 different `id` values it finds to retrieve the full records.

If you make yourself a compound index on `(LeftBounds, id)` you may very well speed up this query by a lot. But it will still have to skip half a million rows, so your `EXPLAIN` may say you're doing a full index scan.

The next thing you might be able to do with this query to speed it up is get rid of `SELECT *`, instead naming the columns you need.  Why does that help? Because it gives a hint at a compound covering index that might help satisfy the query completely.  You've mentioned that `LeftBounds` is unique and therefore a candidate for the `JOIN` criterion.  So, let's explore this with an example. Let's say you want `ParentId, LeftBounds, RightBounds, Level, Name` in your resultset.  Then you could use this query:

```
SELECT Node.ParentId, Node.LeftBounds, 
       Node.RightBounds, Node.Level, Node.Name
  FROM Node
  JOIN (
         SELECT LeftBounds
           FROM Node
          ORDER BY LeftBounds ASC
          LIMIT 500000, 1000
       ) Subset ON Node.LeftBounds = Subset.LeftBounds
  ORDER BY Node.LeftBounds ASC
```

If you have an index on the columns you need, MySQL can satisfy the query from the index.  That index should incorporate these columns in this order.

```
LeftBounds, ParentId, RightBounds, Level, Name
```

`LeftBounds` needs to be first in the index, because that's the column you're using for random access to the index. The point here is to omit having to use the `id`  column to access the table.

Comment: This is a great solution. Even without the compound index it runs about ___5 times___ faster. Out of curiosity - by definition, a Nested Set's `LeftBounds` column must be unique (but not necessarily defined as such in the database) - would it be better to do `JOIN ... ON n.LeftBounds = s.LeftBounds`?

Comment: Also, I don't believe the second `ORDER BY` is necessary.

Comment: See my edit.  As to `ORDER BY`, all SQL servers are free to return result sets in unpredictable orders unless the order is commanded. If you still get the right order when leaving off the second `ORDER BY` it's a side-effect of the way your particular version of MySQL is doing your query, and purely accidental. Seriously. What if the next server generation of MySQL is built on a massively parallel dataflow architecture? Your query **will** break.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I assumed it retained the order because of the `ORDER BY` in the join.

Comment: Right. I learned that ordering rule the hard way on a system that was lucky enough to scale up. I wish there was some kind of SQL Lint, or a mischievous test version of MySQL, or some way to find this stuff.